# How to save query result in a variable vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb6, ssis, smtp

The first vb scripts work fine and can hold the total count in a variable say rowsAffected .
This can be send using smtp  based email using the last statement.

How can i implement the similar situvation in 2nd case?in the 2nd case ,i need to send the result set to email.what modification should i do to hold the result set in a variable ? also how to send that result set

Case 1

```
Dim sqlComm As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
Dim rowsAffected As Integer


sqlComm = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("select count(*) from table1", sqlConn)

rowsAffected = sqlComm.ExecuteScalar()

myHtmlMessage = New MailMessage("email", "email", "This is a testing from  VB script Task", rowsAffected.ToString)
```

---

Case 2

```
sqlComm = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from tabl1", sqlConn)

rowsAffected = sqlComm.ExecuteScalar()   ''what modification needed here?

myHtmlMessage = New MailMessage("email", "email", "This is a testing from  VB script Task", rowsAffected.ToString)  ''what modification here??
```

the sqlComm.ExecuteScalar()  returns integer value,total number of rows for the  first case.

### I need the second case to return all the rows from the table.Also how to send using the smtp email

Public Sub Main()

```
    ''mail variables

    Dim myHtmlMessage As MailMessage
    Dim mySmtpClient As SmtpClient
    Dim value As NetworkCredential

    ''sql variables
    Dim fireAgain As Boolean = True
    Dim sqlConn As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim sqlComm As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand




    Dim cm As ConnectionManager = Dts.Connections("cnn") ''Retrive the reference to the managed Connections

    '' Request an open connection
    sqlConn = cm.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction)
    Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "", "Connection is: " + sqlConn.State.ToString(), "", 0, fireAgain)

    ''Do your work
    sqlComm = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT  [Total_Row_inserted_by this_Load] Column1     ,[Filename] Column2 FROM [Testing-DB].[dbo].[Emailbody]", sqlConn)



    Dim sqlReader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    sqlReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader

    Dim dtDataTable As New DataTable


    dtDataTable.Load(sqlReader)

    ''Inform SSIS you're done your work
    cm.ReleaseConnection(sqlConn)



    For Each row As DataRow In dtDataTable.Rows
        Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "", row("Column1").ToString() + " - " + row("Column2").ToString(), "", 0, fireAgain)

    Next row


    mySmtpClient = New SmtpClient("send.company.net")
    mySmtpClient.Port = 585
    value = New NetworkCredential("my.name@company.net", "pwdddd") ''this is the line added
    mySmtpClient.Credentials = value
    mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = True



    For Each row As DataRow In dtDataTable.Rows


        myHtmlMessage = New MailMessage("my.name@company.net", "my.name@company.net", "Table data is ", row("column1").ToString() + " - " + row("column2").ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine)


    Next row



    mySmtpClient.Send(myHtmlMessage)



    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success


End Sub
```

### my requiremnet is ,to send the result set as an email and the email body should be

### column1 column2

### aa       11

### bb       323

### cvc      342

### aa       11

Comment: Also bear in mind that one thing is VBScript, another thing is VBA/VB6 and another one is VB.NET. Please update your description/tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This block of code will give idea how to do this.

```
sqlComm = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("select Column1, Column2, COUNT(1) CNT from table1  group by Column1, Column2", sqlConn)
Dim sqlReader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
sqlReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader
Dim dtDataTable As New DataTable
dtDataTable.Load(sqlReader)

For Each row As DataRow In dtDataTable.Rows
  Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "", row("Column1").ToString() + " - " + row("Column1").ToString(), "", 0, fireAgain)
Next row
```

rowsAffected = sqlComm.ExecuteScalar() change this line of code to

```
sqlReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader
    Dim dtDataTable As New DataTable
    dtDataTable.Load(sqlReader)
```

myHtmlMessage = New MailMessage("email", "email", "This is a testing from  VB script Task", rowsAffected.ToString) modify this line of code to

```
 For Each row As DataRow In dtDataTable.Rows
myHtmlMessage = New MailMessage("email", "email", "This is a testing from  VB script Task", row("CNT").ToString())
Next row
```

Comment: For Each row As DataRow In dtDataTable.Rows
myHtmlMessage = New MailMessage("email", "email", "This is a testing from  VB script Task", row("CNT").ToString())
Next row  this part is not working

Comment: replace with  this statement ,For Each row As DataRow In dtDataTable.Rows
  Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "", row("CNT").ToString(), "", 0, fireAgain)
Next row , is this working, What is the error you are getting

Comment: No error ..geting only the last row,but i need full resultset..i have added the code above ..please look above...

Comment: added the code in the question section..it seems there is a problem in the last for loop

Comment: do you need to combine all records into single message body text for sending one email? if so, declare string variable "strCombineRecordsCountMessage" and inside the loop, add those records to the variable <strCombineRecordsCountMessage + row("CNT").ToString()> and after this loop ends, add this variable to myHtmlMessage. eg. myHtmlMessage = New MailMessage("email", "email", "This is a testing from VB script Task", strCombineRecordsCountMessage.ToString())